# How to add new object into an arrays after map and check condition

Tags: javascript

How can I add new object if value exist

```
const data = [
          { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', 'child':' Not used', 'status' :' X' },
          { id: '31', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add Child', 'status' :' Y' }
          { id: '32', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add child 2', 'status' :' Y' }
        ]
```

first I map data and if status = X I push new array if not I want to add new object key call child in to  array that've status = X

```
 data.map((element, i) => {
  if (element.status == 'X') {
      arr.push({
          id: element.id,
          mom: element.mom,
          code: element.code
      });
  } else {
      // I want to add element child into arr that has status = X
      arr.push({ child: element.child });
  }
})
```

I want output like this

```
const arr = [
  { 
    id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', 
    child: [
      'name':'add child',
      'name':'add child2'
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: check for only 'X'?

Comment: Your output is invalid you have added key value to Array, please provide valid out put to child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code and your question is a little wrong and hard to understand. Array with key:value, status written with space. So... Sorry if understood it correctly.

### This is what I understood

- Create a new array with all elements with status `X` and put all child of elements with status `Y` in that array by the key `child`.

  ```js
  const data = [
      { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', child: ' Not used', status: 'X' },
      { id: '31', mom: 'B', code: '0141', child: ' add Child', status: 'Y' },
      { id: '32', mom: 'B', code: '0141', child: ' add child 2', status: 'Y' }
  ];

  let objectX = data.filter(val => val.status == "X");
  objectX["child"] = data.filter(val => val.status == "Y").map(c => c.child);
  /*
  [
    { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', child: ' Not used', status: 'X' },
    child: [ ' add Child', ' add child 2' ]
  ]
  */
  console.log(objectX);
  ```

Comment: This returns an array with two elements. The original requirement is "an array with one object element, where the child array is a key on that object". With a small change you can get this with this code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [
          { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', 'child':'Not used', 'status' :'X' },
          { id: '31', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':'add Child', 'status' :'Y' },
          { id: '32', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':'add child 2', 'status' :'Y' }
        ]
const arr =[]

 data.map((element, i) => {
  if (element.status == 'X') {
      arr.push({
          id: element.id,
          mom: element.mom,
          code: element.code
      });
  }
 else {
      if(!arr[0].child) arr[0].child = []
      arr[0].child.push({'name': element.child});
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix mutation and transformation. Take `Array.push` out of your programming vocab and your life will become easier.

This code produces what you want. It won't handle more than the case that you showed, but that's what you asked for.

Your code has syntax errors in it, which made this harder to do than it needed to be. Make sure your code runs and is properly formatted. That will fix 35% of the issues that you run in to as a professional developer.

```js
const data = [
  { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', 'child':' Not used', 'status' :' X' },
  { id: '31', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add Child', 'status' :' Y' },
  { id: '32', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add child 2', 'status' :' Y' }
]

const parents = data.filter(e => e.child === ' Not used')
const children = data.filter(c => c.child !== ' Not used')
  .map(c => ({name: c.child}))
const output = parents.map(p => ({...p, child: children}))
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

For any **NON `X`** statuses

```js
data.map(({child, ...element}) => {
  if (element.status === 'X') {
    arr.push({...element, child: []});
  } else {
    const temp = arr.find((item) => item.status === 'X');
    if (temp) {
      temp.child.push(element)
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, more readable)

```
data.filter((item) => item.status === 'X').map((item) => {
    return item = {
        ...item,
        child: data.filter((item) => item.status !== 'X').map((item) => item.child).map((item) => {
            return {
                ['name'] : item,
            }
        }),
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = [
          { id: '30', mom: 'A', code: '0141', 'child':' Not used', 'status' : 'X' },
          { id: '31', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add Child', 'status' :'Y' },
          { id: '32', mom: 'B', code: '0141', 'child':' add child 2', 'status' : 'Y' }
        ]
```

Please be careful about your array whitespace.

According to your array:  'status': ' X'

But your 'if structure' looked  'status': 'X'.

You can use my array. And check it.

[image]